# Drupal 7 - show categories

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-views

I have created some "Basic Pages" like page 1, page 2, page 3 etc in Drupal 7. I have also created a view named "categories" based on this assigned it in a block. Now I want to show the list of categories **exactly** as below:

```html
<h2 class="sidebar1">Main Menu</h2>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">page 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">page 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">page 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Please help me in this regard. Should I create any view tpl file for this or I need to modify the templates. If so, how can I modify the template files?

Please find the attached screen shot of the view.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean with "Category"? Is it a taxonomy term? I assume Basic Pages have an extra field of type Taxonomy Term, where you specify which category the page belongs to. Right? Could you please upload a screenshot of your view's configuration?

Comment: No, category is not related to "terms" here. I have simply created the pages and created a view based on it.

Comment: Also, I have attached a screen shot of the view.

Comment: The list of categories means to show the list of page titles like page 1, page 2 as stated above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the **Format** label, you have to click "Unformatted list" and then select "HTML list." This way, the view's results will be displayed with the desired HTML format.

Under the **Fields** label, edit "Content: title" and make sure you check the checkbox "Link to content". This way the name of the basic page will automatically be rendered as a link to the page it represents.

Hope it helps.